# Large log data in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I have a couchbase server to storing a huge data.
This data growing daily, but i also daily delete after process it.
Current, this data has about 1320168 items count, with 2.97G of Data Usage
But why Disc Usage is very large with 135G ???

[image]

My disc is lowing space to store more data.

Could delete this data log files to reduce disc Usage?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couchbase uses an `append-only format` for storage. This means that every update or delete operation is actually stored as a new entry in the storage file and consumes more disk space.

Then a process called `compaction` occurs, that will reclaim the unnecessary used space. Compaction can either be configured to run automatically, when a certain fragmentation % is reached in your cluster, or manually on each node.
IIRC auto-compaction is not on by default.

So what you probably want to do is run compaction on your cluster. Note that it may require quite a large amount of diskspace, as noted [here](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Concepts/bp-disk-throughput.html)...

See the [doc](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Tasks/tasks-compaction-process.html) on how to perform compaction (in your case at the end of business day I guess you have an "off-peak" window where you currently delete and could perform compaction).

*PS: Maybe guys in the [official forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/c/couchbase-server) may have more insight and recommandations to offer.*

Comment: Thanks @Simon Baslé , that's all